# How does docker assign and resolve ip address to container?

Tags: docker

I am learning docker. So by default the docker container has no networking. The below dockerfile specifies 0.0.0.0 and port 5000.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Then I run this using:
docker run -p 5000:5000

Any request that comes on the host computers ip address at port 5000 will get forwarded to the container on port 5000.

What is the ipaddress of the container and assuming multiple containers are running, how does docker know that the request has to be passed to this container?

Comment: because ip + port is the target device? i mean, in your pc only one container can listen to a port, so when you do `localhost:5000` it's for sure that container that is going to receive the request

Comment: if two container listens to the same port, then there will be a conflict and the second container will report an error (you will have to use like a reverse proxy to do that)

Comment: So by default, every container gets the same ip address as the host?

Comment: no, every container will have a specific IP associated to its name, and the port be reserved to that container, check this for example https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-a-docker-container-ip-address-explained-with-examples/

Comment: Ok so the binding between host and container is purely based on hostport:containerport?

Comment: exactly, you can have 2 container listening on the same port (e.g. 2 web servers) but you will have to redirect that port to another one when you run it (e.g. the first web server 80:80 and the second one 81:80)

Comment: internally the "software" will  listen to port 80 in both cases, but docker will forward the local port 81 to the container port 80, so that if you do `localhost:81` the second web server will receive the request (but on port 80, since docker will receive the request on port 81, but forward it to port 80)